# Start a task with Action with multiple template args

Tags: c#, multithreading, templates, task

I need to start a Task in C# so I'm creating an action object.

```
private Action<int, int, int> action = (int p1, int p2, int p3) =>
{
    // do some stuff with p1, p2 and p3.
};
```

However, when I try and create a task from it I realise that `new Task` can only take an `Action` or `Action<object>` and refuses to accept my `action` with it's multiple templated arguments.

Do you have any ideas how I can create this task object and have me pass in the args?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a lambda to convert to the right delegate type:

```
Action<int, int, int> action = (int p1, int p2, int p3) =>
{
    // do some stuff with p1, p2 and p3.
};

//a closure can capture over any values you might want to pass in
Task.Run(() => action(1, 2, 3));
```

If your think about it, you cannot hand a `Action<int, int, int>` to `Task.Run` because you also have to supply parameters. `Task.Run` **cannot know what you want to pass in.**

Answer (score -2):

How about creating a class as DTO for your parameters?

```
public class ParamDto
{
   public string Param1;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: I wanted to try and avoid that if I could.

Comment: Well why should you? You have a flexible interface at this point. You only need to modify the class and the method if you need to add or remove a parameter. The rest remains untouched.